# When using MVVM pattern in Android, do I have to use Databinding??

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm

I have a question in Android about architecture.

When using MVVM pattern in Android, do I have to use Databinding??

Comment: You can use data binding but it is not compulsory to use data binding in mvvm.
You can use LiveData to get the updations on the UI in MVVM and can bind the views with ButterKnife

Comment: I think MVVM comes with the predefined ViewModel and Observable concepts, so it is not compulsion but the advisable to use data-binding. Because it will reduce the code and have more flexibility for the data to set.